# Validate ajax request with Data annotations

Tags: ajax, web-services, validation, data-annotations

I am trying to use the Data-annotations to Validate an ajax request

```
var request = $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:55555/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    request: {
                        Id: '34',
                        Value: 'Hello World'
                    }
                }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"

            });
```

Server side:

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld(TestClass request)
    {
        return request.Value;
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    [Range(0,10)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(2)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I was hoping that this would fail since my input parameters doesn't match my required attributes. But instead it works fine and I am able to create the class with my "non valid" parameters 
What am I doing wrong?